# Laravel is it bad to use public static functions in controllers

Tags: php, laravel, static-methods

Is it bad to use public static function in laravel controllers

In my Product model I have a function that look like this:

```
public static function setEndDate($time)
{
   if ($time == 2)                                                 
   {
         return Carbon::now()->addMonths(2)->toDateTimeString();
   }
   else                                                            
   {
         return Carbon::now()->addDays($time)->toDateTimeString();
   }

}
```

And then in my controller I use that function like this:

```
//Validation etc..

$time = Input::get('end_date'); //To transform end-time

$newProduct = new Product();

$newProduct->some_value = Input::get('some_value');
$newProduct->some_value = Input::get('some_value');


$newProduct->end_date = Product::setEndDate($time); //Using my static function like this


newProduct->save();
```

*Is it bad to use static functions like above?*

Comment: It is bad to use static calls in general (best practices should not change just because you slap on latest framework). They cause tight coupling to the specific class names, often hide global state (in form of static variables) and are nightmare to unit-test. **But** you will probably see it in 99.99% of Laravel-related materials. Make your own conclusions ...

Comment: @tereško Nearly none of Laravel's core are static methods. [Laravel Facades](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/facades) make it look like a lot of static but in the background it's actually a service locator pattern.

Comment: @lukasgeiter , laravel's facades **are** service locators (which kinda mean that they are an anti-pattern) and I did not say anything about core classes using static scope. I was pointing out that code which uses laravel almost universally features abuse of static scope in various forms.

Comment: @tereško Alright. Just wanted to make clear that Laravel (the core) doesn't abuse the static scope...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question per se is pretty opinion-based. I won't say it's necessarily bad to have methods like these in your model, although I also don't recommend doing it. (For more information about that check out [@Colin Schoen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27879435/1903366))

Anyways, Eloquent offers a much nicer solution for this specific problem of yours: [Mutators!](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)

They are kind of "setter methods" in where you can modify or *mutate* the value that will be assigned to the property. Here's an example:

```
public function setEndDateAttribute($time){
    if ($time == 2)                                                 
    {
        $this->attributes['end_date'] = Carbon::now()->addMonths(2)->toDateTimeString();
    }
    else                                                            
    {
        $this->attributes['end_date'] = Carbon::now()->addDays($time)->toDateTimeString();
    }
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
$newProduct->end_date = $time;
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything that will inherently break when you create static methods, but as in all documentation, it isn't recommended. Why?

Static state is omnipresent and entirely destroys testability since you can't just reset the state. Additionally, anything could affect the state in ways that other aspects of the code can't predict, resulting in the potential for wildly unpredictable behavior.

Laravel 4 prevents this by using static 'facades'. These facades are "syntactic short-hand for IoC resolution". They provide both syntactic sugar and prevent tightly coupled code.

The classes that are resolved by the facades can be changed and allow you to inject mock systems or whatever you wish.